# Display a new Page based on tracking number search results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a form which stores items in my DB. One of the rows is called "tracking" which is supposed to represent a tracking number followed by other rows like name, status and so on..

I then have a search function which allows you to input a tracking number and it pulls it back if it exist in the DB.

My question is the following;

How do I make the tracking number turn into a "link" a new uniqe page.. For instance, if they search for a tracking number and it exist, it acts like UPS or fedex would and changes the URL to a unique one based on the number and it displays information unique to that number

Here is the code.

```
<?php



$id = "";


if(isset($_POST['Find']))
{




$id = $_POST['id'];


$pdoQuery = $user->search($id);

$pdoResult = $pdoQuery;


$pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":id"=>$id));

if($pdoExec)
{

    if($pdoResult->rowCount()>0)
    {
        foreach($pdoResult as $row)
        {
           echo $row['tracking'];
            $id = $row['id'];

        }
    }

    else{
        echo 'No Data With This ID';
    }
}else{
    echo 'ERROR Data Not Inserted';
}
}


?>
```

```
<head>

    <title> PHP SEARCH DATA USING PDO </title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<body>

    <form action="tracking.php" method="post">

        Tracking Number : <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"><br><br>



        <input type="submit" name="Find" value="Find Data">

    </form>

</body>
```

Basically, I just want to put the tracking number in the search box,  hit enter and it bring up a new page based on that number if it exist in the DB with all of it's information.

Comment: The easiest way would be to turn the form into a GET instead of POST, then you can include the tracking ID in the url

Comment: You can easily getting the results of id on tracking.php there you can make a search and show that to user.

Comment: @Derek Can you show me an example please?

Comment: @Saqlain thanks for telling me how easy it is, doesn not help me

Comment: I guess you mean `column`